# Containers launched with Docker-Compose cannot connect to each other

Tags: docker-compose, zipkin

I have a beginner question with Docker Compose. I am trying to extend the [`docker-compose-slim.yml` example file](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin/blob/master/docker/examples/docker-compose-slim.yml) from [Zipkin GitHub repository](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin).

I need to change it so that it can include a simple FastAPI app that I have written. Unfortunately, I cannot make them connect to each other. FastAPI gets rejected when it attempts to send a POST request to the Zipkin container, even though they are both connected to the same network with explicit links and port mapping defined in the YAML file. However, I am able to connect to both of them from the host, however.

Could you please tell me what I have done wrong?

**Here is the error message:**

```
Error emitting zipkin trace. ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9411): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/spans (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fce354711c0>: Failed to es
tablish a new connection: [Errno 111] **Connection refused**'))"))
```

**Here is the Docker Compose YAML file:**

```yaml
version: '2.4'

services:
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-slim
    container_name: zipkin
    environment:
      - STORAGE_TYPE=mem
    ports:
      # Port used for the Zipkin UI and HTTP Api
      - 9411:9411
    depends_on:
      - storage

  storage:
    image: busybox:1.31.0
    container_name: fake_storage

  myfastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - zipkin
    depends_on:
      - zipkin

  dependencies:
    image: busybox:1.31.0
    container_name: fake_dependencies

networks:
  default:
    name: foo_network
```

**Here is the Dockerfile:**

```docker
FROM python:3.8.5
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "wsgi:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Comment: I would recommend you to bring the three containers into a network.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I thought I did with these statements in the yml "networks: default: name: foo_network". Do I misunderstand how it work?

Comment: I write an answer pls test it.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell the containers the network "foo_network". The External flag says that the containers are not accessible from outside. Of course you don't have to bet, but I thought as an example it might be quite good.

And because of the "links" function look here [Link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#links)

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  zipkin:
    image: openzipkin/zipkin-slim
    container_name: zipkin
    environment:
      - STORAGE_TYPE=mem
    ports:
      # Port used for the Zipkin UI and HTTP Api
      - 9411:9411
    depends_on:
      - storage
    networks:
      - foo_network

  storage:
    image: busybox:1.31.0
    container_name: fake_storage
    networks:
      - foo_network

  myfastapi:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    links:
      - zipkin
    depends_on:
      - zipkin
    networks:
      - foo_network

  dependencies:
    image: busybox:1.31.0
    container_name: fake_dependencies
    networks:
     - foo_network

networks:
  foo_network:
    external: false
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. Unfortunately, I am still having the same issue. 

Error emitting zipkin trace. ConnectionError(MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9411): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v2/spans (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f8c5ae3c460>: Failed to estab
lish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))"))

Comment: This is my zipkin_sender, the only logic that's POSTing to zipkin

def simple_http_zipkin_sender(encoded_span):
    """Simple HTTP sender for zipkin"""
    body = encoded_span

    res = requests.post(
        "http://127.0.0.1:9411/api/v2/spans",
        data=body,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    )
    return res

Comment: You could also try "zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans" So I mean you can address the containers within your Docker Network by container name.

Comment: What happens when you type `curl -s zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans` ?

Comment: I have found the solution! Yes, it works once I renamed the container to zipkin1 and push to zipkin1 instead of zipkin or local host!

Comment: This is a bit strange but then "zipkin" was probably already used internally for something.